# Adding Area51 to Android App sites list

Tags: feature-request, area-51, android-app

I joined Area 51 earlier today. I find out very interesting to track proposed forums, vote on example questions, etc.

When I think of a *downloaded* Android app, I expect nearly all functionality... Which would include Area 51 sample question posting, sharing proposal links, commenting to revise sample questions, etc.

The layout for Area 51 is unique, but I feel that it could be easily translated into the Android app, especially for the future tablet version. You can view proposals by tag (or category). You can easily flag silly sample Qs or comments.